# Notification not working in android 4.4.2 version

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying in implementing push notification in my application. Notification working properly up to `Android 4.3.0` version devices. But in `Android 4.3.0`, when I install app, app not open getting unfortunately application name has stopped. 
when I change service in `manifest file` as `android:name="com.plugin.gcm.GCMIntentService"` to 
`android:name="com.plugin.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"`.

App open in `Android 4.4.2` version, but notification not working in all android versions. push plugin version is 2.4.0.

I am using cordova 3.6.4 version.

If any one have successfully implement push notification in android 4.4.2 version using phonegap push plugin, send me that github link.